# 101 Reputation Users

Tags: discussion

How are there people like [Michael Koper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15436/michael-koper) who have never answered a question or asked a question, yet still have 101 reputation?

Comment: Possible dupe of [this meta SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23064/why-are-there-so-many-users-with-exactly-101-rep-how-much-is-an-up-vote-worth)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are there so many users with exactly 101 rep? How much is an up vote worth?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23064/why-are-there-so-many-users-with-exactly-101-rep-how-much-is-an-up-vote-worth)

Comment: @Rainbolt Your comment is a possible duplicate of my comment, though yours is better formulated, so let's close mine as a duplicate of yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 200 reputation on any Stack Exchange site, and you create an account on another Stack Exchange site, you get a bonus of 100 reputation. This is called a **[site association bonus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)**. It is awarded a maximum of one time per site.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Thanks. Added.